# How to access Reagent Component's children elements correctly?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I'm a clojure/Clojurescript beginner. This is regarding my 1st **Luminus** web app with **Reagent**.
I managed to populate 8 upload buttons by an iteration and fianally using `reagent/render-component` function.

I have a the following hiccup structure in a loop and all the looped items are return as a react component.

```
(let [state_ (reagent/atom (into [] (take 8 (repeat "img/image.png"))))
      state' @state_
      ad-box
      [:div {:class "col-md-3 ui segment "}
       [:img {:class "ui small image"
              :src (nth state' idn)}]
       [:div {:class "ui icon buttons"}
        [:button {:class "ui green button img-btn s-btn"}
         [:i {:class "fa fa-picture-o"}]]
        [:input {:class "inputfile"
                 :type "file"
                 :id (str "ad-pic-" idn)
                 :name (str "ad-pic-file-" idn)
                 :on-change (fn [e]
                              (this-as this
                                (let [el this
                                      name (.-name el)
                                      file (aget (.-files el) 0)
                                      form-data (doto
                                                    (js/FormData.)
                                                    (.append name file))]
                                  (POST "/upload-pics"
                                        {:headers {"x-csrf-token"
                                                   (.-value (.getElementById js/document "token"))}
                                         :body form-data
                                         :response-format :json
                                         :keywords? true
                                         :handler handle-response-ok
                                         :error-handler handle-response-error})
                                  (set-upload-indicator))))}]
        [:button {:class "ui disabled button img-btn r-btn" }
         [:i {:class "fa fa-times"}]]]]]
  ad-box)
```

After creating the Component Upload buttons working as ***type="file"*** behavior. But the issue is I cannot get the uploaded file parameter to send to the backend by ajax request.

Sorry about this question being longer. I'm so much appreciate if you could look in to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
(-> e .-target .-files (aget 0))
```

instead of:

```
(aget (.-files el) 0)
```